# Qt Waiting for QPushButton press

Tags: c++, qt, event-driven

I’m doing my first project in Qt and I have the problem. I know that there are many similar requests on the SO nad Qt forum, but no one answered my question.

I would like to stop the program execution and wait for the click of the button. More or less the situation:

```
slot1() {

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
   /*
    * some code
    */

   // STOP EXECUTION - WAITING FOR THE BUTTON PRESSED

   /*
    * the rest of code
    */
  }

}
```

I know that this is contrary to event-driven programming, but the requirements of the project (task of course on studies) require that way. It is very important for me, so please – give possible solutions :)

Comment: is the `slot1()` for `signal` from the same button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running nested event loop. But other buttons would still be clickable.

```
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
```